# How to use sessionStorage for a webpage for a login user?

Tags: javascript, data-persistence

I have been using sessionStorage for a little bit now. As I came to know sessionStorage persist data till the window or tab is open. One we close the tab, sesstionStorage clears all data and create when new session is created.

Now my Question is How to clear sessionStorage for a particular session in which user logged in and logged out?

As per my investigation I think if we make a AJAX call to get the current user'id and at the time of log out we issue "sessionStorage.clear()" it should clear all the data persistance. Is there any other way to do this.

Note: sessionStorage should cleared out automatically when User logged out from application. Before downvoting, answer the question or just go back to your condo.

Answer (score 1):

when you login

```
//Argument 1 and 2 both have to be strings
sessionStorage.setItem('login','{username: foo, other:sessionData,whatever:bar}')
```

when you logout

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('login')
```

Where `login` is just a name, you can call it whatever you want

Comment: Is "sessionStorage.setItem('login','{username: foo, other:sessionData,whatever:bar}')" gets the user id. as far as i know setItem creates a key-value pair. And about logout this is removeItem('login') will work on event based. right?

Comment: Right. The first argument is the Key (`login`). The second argument is the value. 
In this case `{username: foo, other:sessionData,whatever:bar}`.

If you only want to store a userId in there, it could look like this `sessionStorage.setItem('userId','1234')`

If you need it later you do `sessionStorage.getItem('userId')`
And when the user logs out  `sessionStorage.removeItem('userId')`

Comment: But let me tell you, whatever you do with this data in the frontEnd, make sure, that you control in your backend on each request, that you have the right user. Everyone can send everything to your backend, so just be aware of that